# How do I use both the varchar and Datetime datatypes in a CASE statement using Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

I have an stored procedure and I am using this variable i.e. `@orderBy`.

Here is my code below:

```
ORDER BY
        CASE 
            WHEN @orderBy = 'ClientName' THEN c.LastName
            WHEN @orderBy = 'EmployerName' THEN cda.Name
            WHEN @orderBy = 'EmploymentDate' THEN cda.StartDate
        END
```

The problem is when I'm using the `@orderBy` variable, it is a varchar and it is giving error on the third line:

`Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.`
Working fine if I comment third line i.e. `WHEN @orderBy = 'EmploymentDate' THEN cda.StartDate`

How do I get past this datatype conversion error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this article. It was written in 2003 but still relevant. http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-use-a-variable-in-an-order-by-clause.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case-per-column to remove the mixed types;

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'ClientName' THEN c.LastName END,
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'EmployerName' THEN cda.Name END,
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'EmploymentDate' THEN cda.StartDate END
```

Comment: tell me which one is better solution? Yours or the other one?

Answer (score 3):

You have to separate the datatypes

```
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN @orderBy = 'ClientName' THEN c.LastName
        WHEN @orderBy = 'EmployerName' THEN cda.Name
        ELSE ''
    END,
    CASE 
        WHEN @orderBy = 'EmploymentDate' THEN cda.StartDate
        ELSE '19000101'
    END
```

Or convert smalldatetime to varchar but keep sort logic

```
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN @orderBy = 'ClientName' THEN c.LastName
        WHEN @orderBy = 'EmployerName' THEN cda.Name
        --gives "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.mmm "
        WHEN @orderBy = 'EmploymentDate' THEN CONVERT(varchar(30), cda.StartDate, 121)
    END
```

Or have 3 separate CASEs, as per AlexK's answer

Comment: Okay, 3 separate cases is more appealing to me. Thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

try replace

```
WHEN @orderBy = 'EmploymentDate' THEN cda.StartDate
```

with

```
WHEN @orderBy = 'EmploymentDate' THEN cast(cda.StartDate as VarChar)
```

Comment: tell me which one is better solution? Yours or the othre one?

Comment: "Dec 27 2011" will come before "Jun 28 2011" as **strings**

Comment: he is right. if we compare Jun 28 2011 1:26PM and Aug 01 2011 1:26PM there will be no ascendant order maintained

Comment: you should either apply additional formatting or use the second answer solution

Comment: You can convert it as given in gbn's anser but I'd go for case per column as it is more performant given that no conversion is required.